# VimScript - How do you get file/directory vim was called on from the command line?

Tags: working-directory

I am writing a little hack for vim session that will save and load sessions more conveniently - I am aiming for more project-style sessions.

When you are in directory `my-proj` and call `vim`, it should automatically open the session associated with the current directory. (This is 'almost' working so far - the problem is with getting the current directory). Saving the 'project' (i.e. a session) can be done with `SaveSession`

I have done this so far:

```
let g:session_autosave = 'yes'
let g:session_autoload = 'yes'
let g:session_default_name = getcwd()
```

The minor problem is, if I call `vim ~/x.txt`, `getcwd()` will not return `~/x.txt`. It will return the current directory in bash (which could be almost anything). How can I get the directory that vim was called on in the command line (i.e. `~` in this case)? And if vim was opened with just `vim` then it should get the current working directory.

Comment: Just a hint, but maybe `:h autochdir` will help you.

Comment: I don't think this is what I am looking for. I have nerdtree, so opening a file that is nested within the 'project' will cause the path to be incorrect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get the directory of the first file in `:argv` (the filename arguments when vim was opened): `let g:session_default_name = fnamemodify(argv()[0], ':p:h')`. This will fail if vim was opened with no arguments.

To fallback on `getcwd()` where there were no arguments:

```
" Returns the directory of the first file in `argv` or `cwd` if it's empty
function FindSessionDirectory() abort
  if len(argv()) > 0
    return fnamemodify(argv()[0], ':p:h')
  endif
  return getcwd()
endfunction!
let g:session_default_name = FindSessionDirectory()
```

Comment: I don't think the first option will work since I use nerdtree, so opening a file that is nested within the 'project' will cause the path to be incorrect.

Comment: The second option looks very promising. I shall look into this and attempt to default to `getcwd` where `argv` doesn't work (I am a noob at Vimscript though so this may take a while)

Comment: Added a function with the fallback to cwd()

Comment: I appear to be getting some errors: 

`Error detected while processing function FindSessionDirectory: line    2:  
E15: Invalid expression: ], ':p:h')  
  
E116: Invalid arguments for function fnamemodify(argv()[], ':p:h')  
E15: Invalid expression: fnamemodify(argv()[], ':p:h')  
Press ENTER or type command to continue`

Comment: Oops, I missed a `0` - should be `argv()[0]`. Updated the answer

Comment: Also, `cwd()`  should be `getcwd()`. But thats for the great answer! Since the paragraph about the currently open file is no longer relevant, you could probably remove that now.

Comment: Yikes, now that I've tried it, I've removed the fallback because I can't open a blank vim in some directories. What a good product owner I am being!

`
I ended up using `if len(argv()) > 0  
  let g:session_default_name = fnamemodify(argv()[0], ':p:h')  
endif  
`